# UITableView set it to no selection

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can I set a `UITableView` to default to no selection?  `indexPath.row = -1` or something similar?

Here's my code for creating the table:

```
UITableView* tblThisTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(elementX, elementY, elementW, elementH)];
        tblThisTable.rowHeight = 30.0;
        tblThisTable.layer.borderColor = [colorManager setColor:51.0 :51.0 :51.0].CGColor;
        tblThisTable.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        tblThisTable.delegate = self;
        tblThisTable.dataSource = self;
```

And my implementation of the delegate protocols:

```
#pragma mark - Table View Management
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return arrStates.count;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrStates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [colorManager setColor:66.0 :66.0 :66.0];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    strSelectedState = [arrStates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

I have a data manager class where I check the values of user entries prior to saving them to a plist. Here is the code relevant to the table (I only have the states table):

...

```
} else if ([[_arrAllElements objectAtIndex:i] isMemberOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {

                UITableView* tblThisTable = (UITableView*)[_arrAllElements objectAtIndex:i];

                strElementKey = @"State";
                int selectedRow = tblThisTable.indexPathForSelectedRow.row;
                if(selectedRow > -1) { 
                    strElementValue = [arrStates objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
                } else {
                    strElementValue = @"No Entry";
                }
```

...

So, if a user hits the save button without ever selecting anything in the table I am still getting a 0 value for selectedRow but nothing is showing as selected. I was thinking of UISegementedControls where you can set them to -1 to have no selection. Shouldn't a table do likewise?

Comment: How is `strSelectedState` defined?  If a user doesn't select a row it will remain at its default state.

Comment: strSelectedState is defined as nil but I am not checking that. I have a data manager class where I pass all the objects I need when the user saves, see additional edit above to see how I am checking the table values

Comment: You are checking `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, but you also mentioned that the bug happens when you save before a user makes any row selection at all ("on my test I don't touch the table but the results are always indexPath.row = 0").  What code receives `indexPath.row = 0`?

Comment: I posted it in the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you saving the row?  If you are saving an un-initialized `NSInteger`/`int` that might explain why it's defaulting to `0`.

---

When you ask the table for `indexPathForSelectedRow`, you need to check if it is `nil` before grabbing the `row` property (the `row` of a `nil` path will always be `0`).  This updated code should do what you need:

```
NSIndexPath *selectedPath = tblThisTable.indexPathForSelectedRow;
if (selectedPath != nil) { 
    strElementValue = [arrStates objectAtIndex:selectedPath.row];
} else {
    strElementValue = @"No Entry";
}
```

Comment: I'm not saving anything right now - on view did load I am building the table, I have a save button, when clicked I gather all relevant data - on my test I don't touch the table but the results are always indexPath.row = 0. The table doesn't show a row selection (where it is highlighted in blue). See my edits to the OP.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are gathering those results?  I'm not sure if you're updating an ivar in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or if you're asking the table view for `indexPathForSelectedRow`.  If the latter, it is probably returning a `nil` path and `indexPath.row` will equal `0` in that case.

Comment: Edited the OP - I'm using didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your .m file and it will deselect selected row.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: I should of been more clear - can I do this when I init the table? I have a table of US states and when I go to save the user entries it is defaulting to the first row item (Alabama) when I haven't selected anything. They don't have to pick a state but it can't default to one either.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below will work. Edited your code for creating the cell:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrStates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [colorManager setColor:66.0 :66.0 :66.0];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0];

    return cell;
}
```

I added a line:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

More information can be found here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I don't think he means the cell selection state, he means selection as in "a user's choice".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a all UITableView to default to no selection (scrolling also not touchable)

then use property of table view which is -

```
tableView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
```

And if you want to stop selection of cell then,

```
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Comment: Don't want to do either, I just want it to default to no selection on load.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift

```
// IF tableview selected row
let selectedIndexPath = tableView_Main.indexPathForSelectedRow

if selectedIndexPath != nil {

  tableView_Main.deselectRowAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath!, animated: true)

}
```